# decimals, ints, casting... oh my!

Tags: c#, .net, casting, integer, decimal

I'm going through the "Head First C#" book and in one of the chapters I created a program and uses variables declared as ints and decimals.  Visual Studio got cranky with me a couple of times about mixing and matching the two. For example:

```
dinnerParty.NumberOfPeople = (int) numericUpDown1.Value;
```

NumberOfPeople is declared as an int and apparently numeric updowns are decimals.

Also, the book puts an M after some numbers when adding them together.  For example:

```
public void SetHealthyOption(bool healthy)
{
    if (healthy)
    {
        CostOfBeveragesPerPerson = 5.00M;
    }
    else
    {
        CostOfBeveragesPerPerson = 20.00M;
    }
}
```

CostOfBeveragesPerPerson is declared as a decimal.

So I have two specific questions:

1) How can you know when you need to cast something?  I'm sure there is quite a bit to casting... can anyone provide some good links to learn about casting?

2) What does the M after the numbers do?

*EDIT*

So the M denotes that the number is a decimal and not a double.  Why not just cast the number as a decimal like: (decimal) 50.00?  And what is that "function" called?  If I wanted to see what "letters" were available what would I google?

Comment: The bit after the edit should really be a new question.

Comment: I suppose it could have been.  I guess I just have that "forum" mentality where you are shunned for posting too many threads or whatever.  As you can tell I am fairly new here so I'm trying to do everything by "the book".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Explicit casts are generally needed when there's a loss of precision between the two types. For example, if you had an int and assigned it to a long, no cast is necessary since long can hold all values that an int can. If you were assigning a long to an int, however, a cast would be required as int can hold less values than a long can, which can lead to data loss.
2. The M defines the number as a Decimal type. If you omit this, the number is interpreted as a double.

Comment: Ok sounds good.  So what happens if I cast a decimal, say 10.1 as an int?  Does that then become 10?  What if it was 10.9?  Does it become 11 or is it still 10?

As far as the M defining the number as a decimal, what other options are there?  What's that called if I wanted to google it?

Comment: decimal (and float, double) conversion to int is always a case of removing the decimal part, no rounding is done. Both 10.1 and 10.9 are 10 as int. As for the literal values, 10 is an int, 10.0 is a double, 10.0F is a float and 10.0M is a decimal. No idea what that's officially called though.

Comment: Here's a link that explains it a bit better than I can: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpNumericLiterals.aspx

Comment: Sorry if I am starting to sound dense but if you declare something as a float, why do you need to add the F or the M if you declared as a decimal?  Why declare it if you can just use a letter to denote what it is?

Comment: Nice!  I will mark this as the answer.  I guess what I really needed to know is what a literal actually was.  Using the F or M is simply casting a hard coded number on the fly.

Comment: It just seems to be the way the language is designed. Though in C# 3.0, what you suggest is actually possible. If you use <code>var number = 1.0f</code>, the compiler will figure out the type of <code>number</code> from its usage.

Comment: @Turnor: With floating-point numbers which are *assumed* to be imprecise, type conversion from lower-precision types to higher-precision types is far more likely to indicate a mistake than the reverse, despite .net's decision to follow Java's unfortunate lead in requiring a cast only for the less-trouble-prone direction.  `float f = 1.0/10.0;` shouldn't require a cast (but it does) since it sets `f` to the best `float` representation of 0.1; `double d = 1.0f/10.0f` doesn't require a cast, but the error in the assigned value is millions of times larger than one would expect with a `double`.

Comment: @Turnor: It's funny that the reason .net squawks at conversions from `double` to `Decimal` is probably that such conversions may lose precision or throw exceptions in some cases, but the more problematic cases are actually the ones in which the `Decimal` captures the precisely the nominal value of the `double` actually represents [as distinct from the mathematical value it's "meant" to represent]

Answer (score 4):

```
Type    Suffix          Example
uint    U or u          100U
long    L or l          100L
ulong   UL or ul        100UL
float   F or f          123.45F
decimal M or m          123.45M
```

There's a lot of pages that explain [C# numeric literals.](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpNumericLiterals.aspx) The letter at the end is not a cast or any kind of function. It is syntax showing that what you are writing represents a value of a particular type. So writing (decimal) 5.0 uses a cast, but writing 5.0m does not.

Answer (score 2):

1. Here's a good link on [casting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105(VS.80).aspx) straight from MSDN.
2. The M tells the compiler that the number is a `decimal`, otherwise it will assume it to be a `double`

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I bookmarked that MSDN site as there is a lot of helpful info in there.